# Footer CSS not working

Tags: html, css

I set up some `CSS` styles for a `HTML` page and all was working as expected. I then edited the `CSS` (minimally) and suddenly the layout breaks. I've got a copy of the original (working) `CSS` so I could just go with that. But I wanted to sort out what I did wrong.

So, I've spent a few hours going over the faulty `CSS` but I just cannot find where it is incorrect. Hoping someone can point out the mistake.

In both cases the `HTML` is the same.

I've created 2 CodePens, one with working `HTML/CSS`, the other with same `HTML` and faulty `CSS`. The problem is in the footer area. With the faulty `CSS`, the 'bottom bar' rides up into the main footer above. However, I think I've cleared floats correctly.

Below is what I think is the faulty section of `CSS` (but it will make more sense to view it along with `HTML` - see CodePen links further below):

```
footer{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin-top:200px;
    border-top:6px solid rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.8);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position:left bottom;
    background-size:contain;
    background-color:#b8b8b8;
}

.footer-column-container{
    width:95%;
    max-width:1200px;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:25px 0;
}

.footer-column-container li{
    float:left;
    padding:20px 5px;
    width:25%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.footer-column-container ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}

.footer-links{
    height:250px;
}

.footer-links li{
    float:none;
    display:block;
    line-height:12px;
    padding:8px 0;
    width:100%;
}

.footer-column h4{
    color:#fff;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.footer-column a:link{
    font-size:14px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff; 
}

#bottom-bar-container{
    background-color:#000;
    border-top:1px solid #393939;
    padding:20px 0;
}

#bottom-bar{
    font-size:12px;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:95%;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff; 
}
```

There's a fair bit of code so, rather than place it all here, I'll list links to CodePens:

Link to working `HTML/CSS`: http://codepen.io/Ben10/pen/VjBgyB

Link to working `HTML / Faulty CSS`: http://codepen.io/Ben10/pen/pbkYAd

Many thanks if you can help me.

Answer (score 2):

> you have a floating issues so use `clear:both;` on `#bottom-bar-container`

```
#bottom-bar-container {
  background-color: #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #393939;
  clear: both;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
```

or

> use `overflow: hidden;` to `.footer-column-container`

I hope that will be helpful to achieve you goal

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using floating elements inside footer-column-container, its height won't be set automatically. You need to use `overflow:hidden` in `.footer-column-container` CSS.

That is

```
.footer-column-container{

    width:95%;
    overflow:hidden; /*This property is missing*/
    max-width:1200px;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:25px 0;

}
```

So that the div will accommodate its `floating` child elements , ie the li elements inside footer-column-container.

You have `overflow:hidden` property set in your working CSS. In the faulty code, that property is missing. It is simply the reason why it has messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Add below `overflow:hidden;` into your `.footer-column-container`

```
.footer-column-container{
    width:95%;
    max-width:1200px;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:25px 0;
    overflow:hidden; /*Add this*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` before  `<div id="bottom-bar-container"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Its only need to clear **div**. I check your whole code you need to clear your div. Here updated [fiddle](http://codepen.io/manshu07/pen/kXjmxK).

Here I change your code, Have look..

```
footer{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin-top:200px;
    border-top:6px solid rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.8);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position:left bottom;
    background-size:contain;
    background-color:#b8b8b8;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    clear:both;

}

.footer-column-container{
    width:95%;
    max-width:1200px;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:25px 0;
   display:inline-block
}
```

For more details for clearing div **why and how**  please go here.

1. [learnlayout.com](http://learnlayout.com/clear.html)
2. [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)
3. [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/)

I hope it will help you :)